# Can't create new mailing. Just stop on “Initializing…”

Tags: civimail, drupal

I am running CiviCRM 4.7.13 with Drupal 7.52. We are using php 5.6.23.

When selecting "New Mailing" from the "Mailings" menu, just the message "Initializing... " displayed. Any suggestions ?
Thanks for your help.